# is this has any special pluspoint to have every webpage in seperate folder on server?

Tags: php, html, indexing, server

most websites have their webpages in separate dir. like `example.com/about` so inside it's like (example.com/about/index.php) or `example.com/ask` so inside it's like (example.com/ask/index.php). Why to do it like that ? is it wrong to do it like this = `example.com/ask.php` and `example.com/about.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Human readable URLs are prefereable, mostly for SEO reasons.

Also, with many MVC frameworks, like for example CakePHP, the URL structure will look like they are using subdirectories, when in fact the actual directory structure is much more complex. The entire routing is taken care of by more or less complex routing handlers using Apache's `mod_rewrite`.

So as a simple example CakePHP's application directory structure of:

```
/app/Controller/UsersController.php
/app/Model/Users.php
/app/View/User/index.ctp
/app/Webroot/
```

would result in a URL of:

```
example.com/users
```

Please note that this is a ***very*** much simplified explanation of Cake's directory structure and routing. You can learn more about it at : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't always mean that they are using those as directories.
They could be using pretty url's using a rewrite directive on the server.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will take anything after the example.com/ and send it as a parameter to index.php which then handles the page loading.
So if you typed in example.com/home the server is doing example.com/index.php?uri=home

Then in index.php redirect the 'home' parameter to load the proper page.

Comment: is this effects seo ?

Answer (score 1):

Very few websites now will actually use a drive tort structure like that.

They will use an .htaccess to rewrite the url from `example.com/about` to something like `http://example.com/index.php?url=example.com/about`.

They will then parse the url query and route the request accordingly.